Field on struct being treated as Const in Zig
As a learning exercise, I am trying to create a set type in zig, by building on the hashmap in the std library.
fn Set(comptime T: type) type {
        return struct {
                hashMap : hashMapType,
                const hashMapType: type = std.hash_map.AutoHashMap(T, T);
                const Self = @This();
                fn init(allocator: std.mem.Allocator) Self {
                        return Self{
                                .hashMap = hashMapType.init(allocator),
                        };
                }
                fn put(self: Self, element: T) std.mem.Allocator.Error!void {
                        return try self.hashMap.put(element, element);
                }
                fn count(self: Self) hashMapType.Size {
                        return self.hashMap.count();
                }
        };
}

When I attempt to compile code which uses the put function, I am given the error message:
error: expected type '*hash_map.HashMap(set_experiment.rootPair,set_experiment.rootPair,hash_map.AutoContext(set_experiment.rootPair),80)', found '*const hash_map.HashMap(set_experiment.rootPair,set_experiment.rootPair,hash_map.AutoContext(set_experiment.rootPair),80)'
   return try self.hashMap.put(element, element);
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
set_experiment.zig:26:27: note: cast discards const qualifier
/usr/lib/zig/std/hash_map.zig:551:26: note: parameter type declared here
        pub fn put(self: *Self, key: K, value: V) Allocator.Error!void {
                         ^~~~~

I can see, obviously, that it is complaining because the internal hashmap is being presumed const. What I can't work out is the syntactically and idiomatically correct way to fix this is.

You must to pass a pointer to be able to modify the hashmap. Function arguments are immutable in Zig, which is why the compiler complains about const.
fn put(self: *Self, element: T) !void { ... }

